# Asynchronous xmlhttp request in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement asynchronous XMLHttpRequest in react.
Here is my attempt:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var json_obj, status = false;
xhr.open("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/", true);
xhr.onload = function (e) {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      json_obj = xhr.responseText;
      status = true;
    } else {
      console.error(xhr.statusText);
    }
  }
};
xhr.onerror = function (e) {
  console.error(xhr.statusText);
};
xhr.send(null);

class Welcome extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <img src= {status ?  json_obj[0].url : 'loading...'}></img>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
   <Welcome/>,
   document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

I have been thinking about adding listener to it but i don't know how to do it.

Overall i am having problem with an update after async XMLHttpRequest loads and returns value.

Comment: You should look into using `axios` or `fetch`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the component's lifecycle to load the data and then set the state asynchronously. You will also need to use JSON.parse on the data returned to you.

```js
class Welcome extends React.Component {
  state = {}

  componentDidMount() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var json_obj, status = false;
    xhr.open("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/", true);
    xhr.onload = function (e) {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
          var json_obj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
          status = true;
          this.setState({ json_obj });
        } else {
          console.error(xhr.statusText);
        }
      }
    }.bind(this);
    xhr.onerror = function (e) {
      console.error(xhr.statusText);
    };
    xhr.send(null);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <img src= {this.state.json_obj ?  this.state.json_obj[0].url : 'loading...'}></img>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
   <Welcome/>,
   document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 9):

It is recommended to make AJAX calls in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method.

`componentDidMount` is for side effects. Adding event listeners, AJAX, mutating the DOM, etc.

Also, you should consider using the new [`fetch` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

```
class Welcome extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      data: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/').then(response => {
      return response.json();
    }).then(json => {
        this.setState({ data: json});
    }).catch(error);
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.data) {
      return <img src={this.state.data[0].url} />
    }
    else {
      return <div>Loading...</div>
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to perform the ajax request within the React lifecycle. The easiest way is to listen to `componentDidMount`, perform your ajax request, and then set the state.

```
class Welcome extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      data: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var status = false;
    xhr.open("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/", true);
    xhr.onload = function (e) {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
          this.setState({ data: xhr.responseText });
          status = true;
        } else {
          console.error(xhr.statusText);
        }
      }
    };
    xhr.onerror = function (e) {
      console.error(xhr.statusText);
    };
    xhr.send(null);
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.data) {
      return <img src={this.state.data[0].url}></img>
    }
    else {
      return <div>Loading...</div>
    }
  }
}
```

You can read more about the component lifecycle here:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html

- Note that this example doesn't handle for the fact of your component being unmounted before the XHR request finishes. Out of simplicity's sake, not including it here.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend hooking to the componentDidMount lifecycle event and make your request there. Then, once it has finished, call `setState` to update the state which will re-render your component. Check out the video here if you need more info:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YpM3YK9Uue0