# How do I get a string from a file path?

Tags: reactjs, filepath

I have a file path in my react website and want to get the contents from that file.

I have tried the fs `readFile` but it just gives me `TypeError: Object(...) is not a function.` I'm not sure that's the way to go.
I have done some searching but I'm very new to react and javascript so I haven't found anything.

Here's my code

```
import { readFile } from "fs";
...
readFile("../../../" + filePath,'utf8').text}
```

where ""../../../" + filePath" is a relative path to the markdown file I want.

I expect the readFile() to return just a string that looks something like

```
Hello!  
This is **markdown** text
```

in one string but right now it just gives me the error I gave above as soon as it's run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fs` object exists in Node.js, and React is a browser framework.  You can't read a file from the filesystem in the browser - that would be a security problem.

Instead, you probably want to issue an [XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45701929/asynchronous-xmlhttp-request-in-react) to fetch the content from the server at which point you can manipulate the content in the browser context.

Answer (score 1):

You can't open a file in javascript that runs on browser's side. This will be a security issue, coz everyone will be able  to write scripts which will get all the files from the user's filesystem and push them on some server.

The *readFile()* directive comes from nodejs, so if you have a nodejs server which represents the backend than you will have the posibility to open/read and write to file.